# What is reliable way to clip *content* of a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, web

I wonder how it is possible to (more or less ) reliably clip the content from a random web site (using Ruby or JavaScript, doesn't really matter).

Much like Evernote and Flipboard do.

What is the best way to determine **where** the actual content is within a page?

The purpose: given a URL - retrieve the **actual content** of that page and ignore all the layout and other **unrelated information**.

For example:

- given http://ninemsn.com/ => the HTML of the main news topic that is in the middle part of the content.
- given the http://news.cnet.com/8301-1035_3-20104048-94/a-beginners-guide-to-telecom-jargon-part-7 => the HTML of the main article.

Just use Evernote's "clip full page" option to see exactly what I mean.

Thanks.

Comment: I think this is a great question; I too would be interested in learning about this. I'm posting a comment here as a bookmark so I can find this question later if someone answers it.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by "clip"? Does this mean to data mine the HTML on the page or are you trying to render it to an image, for example?

Comment: By clipping I mean extracting actual content of the page. Be it HTML or an image - it's another question. The question is how to find where the actual content is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial thoughts would be to DOM parse the page, then traverse the DOM tree to the content of a specific `div` and show that (via XPath, etc). For pages without clearly-defined sections it's going to be difficult regardless of which method you use. The [AutoPager](http://www.teesoft.info/) plugin for Firefox and Chrome implements XPath parsing behaviour. Get the latest version and open up the `.xpi` to see how he does it. It's a JavaScript implementation.

Pick the div by letting someone enter, per URL/site scheme, what the `id` or `class` of the content `div` is. For your ninemsn example, the div containing the article's title, share buttons, the author's image, and the post content is

```
<div class="post">
```

and the actual body of the text is

```
<div class="postBody txtWrap" section="txt">
```

So someone would enter that you need to parse the first `h1` from `<div class="post">` and that's the article title, and then get all the text from `<div class="postBody">` and make that the article content (you might need to parse the class in such a way that it can match both `postBody` and `txtWrap`).

Another example (for funsies): Stack Overflow. A question's title is contained in

```
<div id="question-header">
```

A question's text is trickier, because it's in a `div` with the same `class` as an answer's text, and no `id`. You need to match `<div id="question">` and then traverse down to

```
<div class="post-text">
```

Similarly for answers, each `<div id="answer-[UINTEGER]">` contains a `<div class="post-text">` with its respective text.

In both situations, you can traverse those top-level `question` and `answer-` divs for `<div class="user-details">` to fetch usernames, reputation and badge counts, etc.

Comment: How do you determine the necessary CSS/XPath selectors to work with most of the web sites? Hardcoding each of them doesn't look good to me.

Comment: And yeah. Thanks for the AutoPager link.

Comment: Due to very loosely kept `HTML` standards, there's next to no reliable way to do it. It's why AutoPager has a repository of user-submitted configurations which work for a particular website. There's no good answer to this, unfortunately. You can start by looking for `post`, `body`, `content`, `main` as the `id` or `class` of a `div` or `p` block. You could set up a similar system to AutoPager whereby configurations are "known" and if one isn't known you can either get a user to add it and then you proof the new config, or just present a message indicating this site isn't supported yet.